# Sails js 2:n relation

Tags: associations, sails.js, waterline

I recently started working with SailsJS, and I found the process of defining attributes and associations very elegant. However, there is one thing I cannot find out:

I have a model Couple(person1, person2). I'd like to create an association in Person, that lists every couple they are a member of. Something along the lines of:

```
attributes{
    //other attributes,
    couples:{
        collection: 'couple',
        via: 'person1, person2'
    }
}
```

My current method is:

```
attributes{
    //other attributes,
    couples1:{
        collection: 'couple',
        via: 'person1'
    },
    couples2:{
        collection: 'couple',
        via: 'person2'
    },
    getCouples: function() {
        return this.couples1 + this.couples2;
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem very pretty, is there a way to do it more elegantly?

Comment: Is the couple model necessary?, paste both models code, and please name which is which. Not quite sure yet of what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If i get your question correctly, you want a person and its couple, i'm assuming you have a monogamous relationship in your couples (meaning one person belongs to the other and vice-versa) you can make an association with the same model, like this.

```
var Person = {
  attributes: {
      name: {type:'string'},
      couple: {model: 'Person', via: 'couple'}
  }
};

module.exports = Person
```

Then you can create and associate them like this. (Assuming sails console)

```
Person.create({name: 'John Doe', couple: {name: 'Jane Doe'} }).exec(console.log)
Person.update(2, {couple:1}).exec(console.log)
```

And retrieving them is as easy as

```
Person.find({name:'John Doe'}).populate('couple').exec(console.log)
```

You can try to associate them with `.add` and `.save` but i'm not sure if it works when the association points to the same model, so check that out.

Another option is to have it like this:

```
var Person = {
  attributes: {
      name: {type:'string'},
      couple: {model: 'Couple', via: 'persons'}
  }
};

module.exports = Person;
```

Couple model holds a collection of persons, so you can add persons to the
couple model, and associate them later with the person.couple attribute.

```
var Couple = {
  attributes: {
    persons: {collection: 'Person', via: 'couple'}
  }
};

module.exports = Couple;
```

Or you could use what you have, which is not ideal in this case, but it works.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Well, in theory a person could be part of multiple couples. That's why I didn't make couple an attribute of Person, because that limits it to only one couple per person.

I'm thinking of making it a n:n relationship, so that a couple can have more than two persons associated with it, but at least that can be prevented by just entering data correctly, and it won't look ugly in the API.